# CakePHP unique rule on separate table fields

Tags: php, database, validation, cakephp

I am trying to create a unique rule on two tables (that are related)
Importers (client_id) and ImporterDetails (email), and whilst i can independtly get them unique, im struggling with getting them into the same ruleset. When running tests, the issue i get is that
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Importers.ImporterDetails.email`
Unique rule is built ideally something similar in one of the tables,
ImporterDetails

```php
$rules->add($rules->isUnique(
            ['client_id', 'ImporterDetails.email'],
            'This email address has already been used for this client'
        ));
```

or

```php
$rules->add($rules->isUnique(
            ['email',],
            'This email address has already been used for this client'
        ));
```

not used to building a unique rule across entities within symfony. Docs haven't really helped and not sure i fully understand them at this point (fairly new to validation rules most of them understand)

Comment: That's not supported, the unique rule can only operate on a single table. Do you know how to do that check using plain SQL?

Comment: yeah know how to do it with plain sql, just wondered if there'd be a quicker way is all